# operator overloading internal call conversion

Tags: c++

If there is a class

```
class complex
   {
     private:
        float real,imag;
     public:
       complex operator +(complex c)
       {
         complex t;
         t.real=real+c.real;
         t.imag=imag+c.imag;
         return t;
       }
```

and in main if we call overloaded operator by

c3=c1+c2;

then compiler internall converts as c3=c1.operator+(c2)

similarly in similar example of operator overloading,chaining of =

```
class circle
  {
    private:
      int radius;
      float x,y;
    public:
      circle()
      {}
      circle(int rr,float xx,float yy)
      {
        radius=rr;
        x=xx;
        y=yy;
      }
      circle& operator=(const circle& c)
        {
          cout<<endl<<"assignment operator invoked";  
          radius=c.radius;
          x=c.x;
          y=c.y;
          return *this;
        }
int main()
{
    circle c1 (10,2.5,2.5);
    circle c2,c3;
    c3=c2=c1;
    c1.showdata();
    c2.showdata();
    c3.showdata();
    return 0;
}
```

Overloaded = to operator will be called 2 times first for c2=c1 and then for c3=c2.
then how will compiler treat c2=c1 with its function prototype??how will compiler internally convert this overloaded operator = call??(plz tell in reference with above addition example)
Whose private fields will b accessed and to ahich object value will be returned??

Comment: `c3 = c1 + c2;` -> `c3.operator=(c1.operator+(c2));` and `c3 = c2 + c1;` -> `c3.operator=(c2.operator=(c1));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
c3=c2=c1;
```

is similarly evaluated as

```
c3.operator=(c2.operator=(c1))
```

`c2.operator=(c1)` returns a reference to `c2` after it was assigned `c1`.

Note that for your class, you don't need to overload `operator =` since the compiler-generated one does **the exact same thing**.

And if you do, you should obey **the rule of three** - and also add a destructor and copy constructor. But, again, your class doesn't require either.

Comment: overloaded = will be invocked 2 times??

Comment: @amadeus yes, once for c2, once for c3.